# mounting a SharePoint document library using davfs in Linux

Tags: linux, webdav, davfs2

I was able to install `davfs2` and I can even mount the SharePoint document library using it but when I try to do anything on the mount I get an error.

I can mount the document library:

```
root@host:/# mount -t davfs "http://sharepoint/Shared Documents" /mnt/sp
Please enter the username to authenticate with server
http://sp/Site Stuff or hit enter for none.
  Username: username
Please enter the password to authenticate user nacho with server
http://sp/Site Stuff or hit enter for none.
  Password:
```

I can CD to it and I can see it mounted since there:

```
root@host:/# cd /mnt/sp
root@host:/mnt/sp# ls
Forms  lost+found  home.html
```

But when I try to create a file or do anything I get an error:

```
root@host:/mnt/sp# touch a
touch: setting times of ‘a’: No such file or directory

root@host:/mnt/sp# date > hi.txt
bash: hi.txt: Invalid argument
```

Anyone have any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I met this problem today, and as the fix I applied works fine, here it is.

It looks like the WebDAV default option *use_locks* is set to value 1 in the DAVFS configuration file `davfs2.conf`.

Here is an excerpt of the manual of this file (provided by the command `man davfs.conf`):

> ```
>  use_locks
> Whether to lock files on the server when they are opened for writing.  0 = no, 1 = yes.
> Default: 1
> ```

I would recommend changing the `use_locks` value to 0 by adding the line

```
use_locks 0
```

either in the system wide DAVFS configuration file (usually: `/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf`) or in the user customized file (usually: `~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf`).

Comment: Thank you. I don't have a computer I can test on right now but I will check it as soon as I do.